# Troubles with keeping footer below content

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having a few issues keeping my footer at the bottom of the page and below the content. I currently have it sitting at the bottom of the page, just keeping it below the content seems to be the issue.

My footer layout is:

```
#footer
    #footer-content
        p.copyright
        p.credit
    /#footer-content
/#footer
```

My stylesheet:

```
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 940px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #aaa;
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer-content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Setting position to absolute makes the whole footer disappear somewhere off the page so I can't just change that.

What can I do to keep my footer below the content? I'm open to any JavaScript solutions.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2gLgrLqL/2/) (Since it's WordPress I can't copy over everything)

**EDIT:**

Made a few edits. Still doesn't change my problem.

Comment: add a fiddle or jsbin with your code please!

Comment: do you want a sticky footer that is always at the bottom of the page, regardless the length of the content, or just a footer that is always below the content?

Comment: @DoXick It has to be below the content and at the bottom of page (not always bottom of viewport)

Comment: okidoki, a sticky footer it is. create a jsfiddle and i will fix your code to do that :-)

Comment: @doxick There is a fiddle linked at the bottom of my question

Comment: ok, looking at your code, you need to remove all the fixed positioning. There is no way to make and element to behave relative to another element, if the elements are `position: fixed`

Comment: do you have anything else at the bottom of the page that could interfere?

Comment: @DoXick I no longer have any `position: fixed` located in the stylesheet. I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: i'll take a look in a bit. work work... sorry for the delay :-)

Answer (score 6):

What you are describing is a footer that's on the bottom of the content. Defining the stuff in your footer div is unneeded information. You could have a diamond unicorn in the footer for all we care. The real information that's needed is the basic layout aka header region, content region, sidebar regions, footer region.

here is a live demo of what this will do http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

This will expand the content on short content to push the footer to the bottom. for longer content the footer is under the content as the content gets bigger.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

You need a container that will take up the view area and by setting the footer div to the absolute bottom of the container it will be on the bottom. the content "body" will expand the container as needed and the footer will be on the bottom just under the content every time. divs by default have a display:block so they will push to the next line every time.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code across any websites that I make and it works for me -

```
#footer{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: That's the same I have now with `display: block` so it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that all your `position: fixed` is causing the problem, so I've tried cleaning it up for you in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09qez7uu/).

The position: fixed; sets the divs position relative to the browser-window, and not the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have editted your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gLgrLqL/3/) to apply a ['sticky footer'](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Your document structure had to change for that:

```
body
  #container
    ...content...
    #wrap-push
  #footer
```

added this css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container
{
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -107px;
}
#wrap_push
{
    height: 107px;
}
#footer
{
    height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS variables are broadly available ([April](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) [2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)), I created some variables for vertical padding/margin and configured a content wrapper to have as minimum height: `calc(100vh - paddings - footerHeight)`

The [`vh` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) is a percentage of the view height.

Minimum working example:

Use the variable-size textarea to test if it always keeps as much spacing as you want it to :)

```css
:root {
  --page-padding-bottom: 62px;
  --footer-margin-top: 35px;
  --footer-height: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: var(--page-padding-bottom);
}

#content-wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - var(--page-padding-bottom) - var(--footer-margin-top) - 20px);
}

footer {
  margin-top: var(--footer-margin-top);
  height: var(--footer-height);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id=content-wrapper>
        <textarea style='resize: vertical'>...Page content...</textarea>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <a href='https://codeberg.org/...'>This site is open source!</a>
    </footer>
</body>
```

I used this solution because it feels nonhacky, but the downside is that you need to know how tall your footer is.