# Adding HTML code with js messes up my footer position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've followed some guides to get the footer to be on the bottom of the page but... It works on all pages except my blog entries where I load the comments underneath the post. Here's a picture:

[Footer over content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90OuP.jpg)

Here is my css main content:

```
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.footer{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 250;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I followed this for this css style: [Troubles with keeping footer below content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870365/troubles-with-keeping-footer-below-content)

and my HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
    </body>
    <footer class="footer">
    </footer>
  </html>
</div>
```

In my blog entry I load comments from Firebase Database:

```
function buildCommentSection(data, parentHTML){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = (`
            <div class="single-comment">
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="avatar-comment" style="background-image:url(${data.userPicture})"></div>
                        <p class="comment-author">
                            ${data.userName}
                        </p>
                </div>
                    <p class="comment-description">
                    ${data.body}
                    </p>
            </div>
            </br></br>
        `);
        parentHTML.appendChild(div);

}
```

I'm gessing this happens because the js runs after the page is loaded and it cant see there is content yet. Is there any fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put the `footer` inside the `body` tag. footer should not be outside body

Comment: Following the previous comment, your html tag should not be between a div, and your header as well should be inside your body tag.... You should go and read about basic HTML structures before going any further

Comment: You could also try changing the footer's position from absolute to sticky

Comment: As the footer tag should be the last child of the body tag, you could use the parentnode.insertBefore(newnode, existingnode) functionality to insert the new div above it (where "existingnode" refers to the footer tag and "parentnode" refers to the body tag)

Comment: Yup, I got things mixed up. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function addNew() {
  let n = document.getElementById("newtext").value;
  let t = document.createElement("div");
  t.innerHTML = n;
  let b = document.body;
  let f = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
  b.insertBefore(t, f);
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

```css
footer{
    background-color:white;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin:0;
    position: sticky;
    border-top:1px solid red;
}
header{
    background-color:white;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    margin:0;
    position: sticky;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
body{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
#newtext {width:500px;}
```

```html
<header>This is for the header<br>
Enter new text: <input type="text" id="newtext"><button onclick="addNew();">Add</button>
</header>
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </div><div>Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz. </div>
<footer>This is the footer
</footer>
```

Comment: ps, if you run the snippet, click the "Full page" link to see the full effect

Comment: Hey @ATD! thanks for the response, but I'm still having some issues. I've changed the footer to sticky. But as on page reload, the getComments get called, all I do is add everyhting to the parent div and when I put body.insertAfter(parentDiv, footer), I still have the same issue. Have you got any other idea?

Comment: It should be body.insertBefore(...) as that inserts the new stuff before the footer element.