# Keep footer fixed at the bottom of the screen when keyboard opens?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever someone enters an input a sticky footer is always following the top of the keyboard. Is it possible to leave the footer at the bottom of the page and place it under the keyboard?
Screenshot explanation:

[image: Screenshot explanation]

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <input id="my-input" placeholder="type something..." />
</div>
<div class="footer fixed">This is my footer</div>
```

css:

```
.content {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
}
#my-input {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ticasem679/pen/dyMaWba)

Comment: Have a look at: [sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011308/adding-html-code-with-js-messes-up-my-footer-position)  The footer is actually in a `footer` tag and styled as `position:sticky` and `bottom:0px` styling to keep it at the bottom.

Comment: It can't be done

Comment: AFAIK the keyboard does not influence the layout.

Comment: AFAIK not doable unless you want to go full custom mode and replace native keyboard with some javascript implementation.

Comment: Nope, can't be done and you shouldn't invest more time in this approach.

Comment: got it, thank you guys